# Parallel image convolution filter using dynamic load scheduling: artifacts

Tags: java, multithreading, image-processing, convolution

I am having the following problem: I've created a parallelized prewitt filter based on [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.403.1706&rep=rep1&type=pdf) using the dynamic load scheduling approach. Unfortunately, I am experiencing artifacts that my serialized filter does not show, showing up at seemingly random places which implies to me that I have a synchronization issue in the threads. However I can't figure out where it is. I have a very similar greyscale filter which ...up until now showed no similar issues but now does.

[image: desired result] [image: result from parallel filtering]
The left picture is the desired result, achieved with a sequential algorithm, the right one shows the aforementioned artifacts in the bottom.
With further testing I am now fairly certain that my threads skip certain portions of the image without filtering them. I will continue to investigate.

The structure of my code is as follows: ParallelPrewittFilter inherits from ParallelSobelianFilter and only implements a factory method creating the right kind of worker, namely the following one (a class implementing the runnable interface). PrewittFilterWorker inherits from SobelianFilterWorker (which in turn inherits from ParallelFilterWorker) and implements only a method which returns the convolution kernel. Hence I will now post the relevant code from ParallelSobelianFilter and SobelianFilter worker. The last code block is the load scheduling code.

ParallelSobelianFilter:

```
public BufferedImage applyFilter(BufferedImage image) {
  //taking the red and alpha channels from image and placing them
  //in the arrays red[width*height] and alpha[width*height]

  ParallelFilterWorker.resetDynamicLoadCounter();
  for (SobelianFilterWorker worker : workers) {
    worker.setSourceArrays(width, height, alpha, red, green, blue, hasAlpha);
    worker.setDestImage(result);
  }

  for (Thread thread : threads) {
    System.out.println("starting thread ");
    thread.start();
  }

  for (Thread thread : threads) {
    try {
      thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

SobelianFilterWorker:

```
protected void filterPixel(int index) {
  //[..]
  if (x < 1 || y < 1 || x > width - 2 || y > height - 2) {
    //do nothing
    color = red[index];
  } else {
    firstPass = red[index - 1] * kernel[0][1] + red[index + 1] * kernel[2][1]
        + red[index - width - 1] * kernel[0][0] + red[index - width] * kernel[1][0] 
        + red[index - width + 1] * kernel[2][0] + red[index + width - 1] * kernel[0][2]
        + red[index + width] * kernel[1][2] + red[index + width + 1] * kernel[2][2];

    //transposed kernel
    secondPass = red[index - 1] * kernel[1][0] + red[index + 1] * kernel[1][2]
        + red[index - width - 1] * kernel[0][0] + red[index - width] * kernel[0][1] 
        + red[index - width + 1] * kernel[0][2] + red[index + width - 1] * kernel[2][0]
        + red[index + width] * kernel[2][1] + red[index + width + 1] * kernel[2][2];
    color = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(firstPass * firstPass + secondPass * secondPass));
  }
  if (color > 255) {
    color = 255;
  }
  // ... color turned into an ARGB integer argb
    destImage.setRGB(x, y, argb);      
  }

}
```

I suspect the error is in the above two blocks, as the following code works fine when filterPixel is a simple greyscale filter:

ParallelFilterWorker:

```
private static final int loadPerInterval = 500;

private static volatile int dynamicLoadCounter = 0;

public static synchronized void resetDynamicLoadCounter() {
  dynamicLoadCounter = -loadPerInterval;
}

public void run() {
  if (checkNull()) {
    return;
  }

  int localCounter = loadPerInterval - 1;
  int start = 0;
  while (dynamicLoadCounter < width * height) {
    localCounter++;
    if (localCounter == loadPerInterval) {
      //fetch a package of pixels to work on and mark them as being worked on
      start = syncCounterUp();
      System.out.println("#" + threadID + " starting at " + start);
      localCounter = 0;
    }
    if (start + localCounter < width * height) {
      filterPixel(start + localCounter);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}

private static synchronized int syncCounterUp() {
  dynamicLoadCounter += loadPerInterval;
  return dynamicLoadCounter;
}
```

What's going wrong, am I missing a synchronization? I would be very interested in an explanation what exactly my threads are doing and why these artifacts are appearing. Thank you for having a look!

Comment: I was hoping to get help, my bad.

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to figure out what is wrong in your code. What would help is to show us an image and the result when you use a single thread.

Comment: @JayElf So you successfully waited one painful hour for people on the internet to solve your problem before wallowing in self-pity? I would need an hour just to find out what your code shall do! Please provide sample input, output and a runnable main method.

Comment: @Gilfoyle nah, sorry, my response was towards a particularly snarky guy being rather rude to me, but his response apparently got deleted - I didn't mean to say "omg u no help me within 10 min", it was just that he was being snarky and  I was a bit annoyed at that. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heureka! My problem was much simpler than I thought. I was thrown off by the fact that, initially, it seemed that my greyscale filter worked fine, which really, it didn't. Here's the solution:

```
public void run() {
  if (checkNull()) {
    return;
  }

  int localCounter = loadPerInterval - 1;
  int start = 0;
  while (start + localCounter < width * height) {
    localCounter++;
    if (localCounter == loadPerInterval) {
      start = syncCounterUp();
      localCounter = 0;
    }
    if (start + localCounter < width * height) { 
      filterPixel(start + localCounter);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the run method in ParallelFilterworker. I have changed the condition for the while loop.

What was happening, was that for some threads, the while condition turned to false, as other threads had already acquired the last remaining pixels while this thread was still busy with some. This caused the thread to abandon the pixels it vouched for as it thought everything was done. What a silly mistake. Thank you very much for everyone's answers and time!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using a ThreadPool and feeding it with Callable. This seams a bit over engineered because of the locks, but it keeps your threads apart, even if one image is not finished with the first filter pass and is used in a second pass. 
Here an Example on how this could work:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Filter {
    int lockcount = 0;
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    List<Worker> fpThreads = new ArrayList<Worker>();
    List<Worker> spThreads = new ArrayList<Worker>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Map<Integer, Object> lockMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new Hashtable<Integer, Object>());


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Filter filter = new Filter();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Worker w1 = new Worker();
            filter.fpThreads.add(w1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Worker w1 = new Worker();
            filter.spThreads.add(w1);
        }

        filter.filer();
    }


    public void filer() {
        runPass(lockMap, fpThreads);
        runPass(lockMap, spThreads);
    }

    private BufferedImage runPass(Map<Integer, Object> lockMap, List<Worker> threads) {
        Future<BufferedImage> future = null;
        Object lock = null;
        for (Worker thread : threads) {
            lock = lockMap.get(worker.hashCode());
            if (lock == null) {
                lock = thread;
                lockMap.put(thread.hashCode(), lock);
                future = executor.submit(thread);
            } else { //we have a lock
                waitOnLock(thread, lock);
            }
        }
        try {
            //get() waits until it gets an result
            return future.get();

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (lock) {
            lockMap.remove(lock.hashCode());
            lock.notifyAll();
            System.out.println("Notify: " + lock.hashCode() + " with " + lockcount + " locks in use.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void waitOnLock(Worker thread, Object lock) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                lockcount++;
                System.out.println("Wait: " + thread.hashCode() + " with " + lockcount + " locks in use.");
                lock.wait();
                lockcount--;
                System.out.println("Continuing: " + thread.hashCode() + " with " + lockcount + " locks in use.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Worker implements Callable<BufferedImage> {

    public BufferedImage call() throws Exception {
        //Here you do you filtering
        System.out.println("Thread called: " + this.hashCode());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return null;
    }
}
```

For your purpose you might implement the worker to do your filtering.

Comment: Wow, this is a really elaborate response, thank you very much. I will look through this and see what's going on. (I have since realized that two passes are not necessary and I can do it all in one pass, so I can simplify it a bit more)

Comment: While it didn't specifically solve my problem, your answer was very informative and introduced me to concepts I hadn't known before. Thank you!